# Should I include adminlte in packages.json / composer.json file?

Tags: frontend, adminlte

Should I include adminlte in packages.json / composer.json file?

Is there necessary to include it in my packages.json / composer.json for my FE library?

Or I just download the zip file add to my public/ folder will be easier?

Since I am using version control, I will easily find out the file changes.

Is anyone added to their packages.json / composer.json? What is the advantage?

Anyone mind to share their workflow. I found that everytime have new update. That will be challenged to update.

I think it is same goes to other Front End Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the needed functions, include the whole package if this isn't expressly needed could lead to additional security problems under certain circumstances.

I suggest you to give a look to AdminLTE structure. 
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/documentation/index.html

Comment: so your point of view, there is no need to added to composer.json / packages.json files. since you just add what you are needed. I want to know more other developer workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Forget everything. AdminLTE can be installed using multiple methods.
Try this:

#### Via npm

```
npm install admin-lte --save
```

#### Via composer

```
composer require "almasaeed2010/adminlte=~2.4"
```

#### Via composer

```
bower install admin-lte
```

Comment: Yes, I do know it can be installed via the following method. But my questions is if u included. What is the advantage, since I can download the zip file and git version control the file?